# Как средствами php подсчитать количество объектов с одинаковым классом на странице?

Tags: php

Предположим есть страница:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class='somename'></div>
 <div class='somename'></div>
 <div class='somename'></div>
 <div class='somename'></div>
 <div class='somename'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Как с помощью php подсчитать все элементы с классом somename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри одного файла можно прочесть и самого себя. Условно говоря файл для этого назовём **dom-2.php** содержимое целиком:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dom-2 :)</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class='somename'>1</div>
    <div class='somename'>2</div>
    <div class='somename'>3</div>
    <div class='somename'>4</div>
    <div class='somename'>5</div>


    <pre>

    <?php
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTMLFile("dom-2.php");
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
    $classname="somename";
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

    print_r($nodes);
    ?>

    </pre>

</body>

</html>
```

Но при этом ваша задача в текущей озвучке становится какой-то бессмысленной. Если страница формируется при помощи вашего же **php**, то никакой DOM не нужен, чтобы узнать количество элементов, которые мы туда сами и насовали.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы не уточняете задачу, то предположу, что вам нужен отдельный php-файл для подсчёта элементов. В php, для того, чтобы заняться анализом или формированием HTML потребуется [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php). А для более углублённой работы, например с классами — [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domxpath.php).

Ваш отдельно написанный файл будет представлять из себя что-то такое:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("page.html");
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="somename";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

print_r($nodes);
```

В зависимости от контекста работы вторая строка будет выглядеть как

```
$dom->load("page.html");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш вариант ответа. Мне надо что бы подсчет выполнялся в одном файле. Есть ли какие-нибудь способы выполнения этого в одном файле?